# While loop doesn't wait for method completion

Tags: c++

So it's been a while since I did anything in C++, but I'm getting a very strange behavior from my while loop. It's designed to allow the user to execute an infinite number of commands, and determines which command(s) to execute by contents of a string.

Here's the code of interest:

```
    string run;
    size_t found;
    bool understood;
    while (true)
    {
          run = "";
          found = string::npos;
          cout << "Please enter command(s)" << endl;
          cout << "\> ";
          cin >> run;
          found = run.find("convert");
          cout << found << endl;
          understood = false;
          if (found != string::npos) 
          {
                  cout << "Converting DNA" << endl;
                  understood = true;
                  convert();
          }
          found = run.find("purify");
          if (found != string::npos)
          {
                  cout << "Purifying DNA" << endl;
                  purify();
                  understood = true;
          }
          found = run.find("build");
          if (found != string::npos)
          {
                  cout << "Building overlaps" << endl;
                  buildOverlaps();
                  understood = true;
          }
          found = run.find("close");
          if (found != string::npos)
          {
                    cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
                    break;
          }
          if (understood == false) cout << "I'm sorry, I didn't understand you" << endl;
    }
```

I moved from my original method, which just involved if string == "string" so that multiple commands can be executed by the same line. However, when I run this new code I get

```
Please enter command(s)
> run converter
(some long, nonzero, number)
I'm sorry, I didn't understand you
Please enter command(s)
> 0
Converting DNA
```

So basically, it appears to take in the string, skip the if blocks (except for the last one), then wrap back around and execute the appropriate method. It all works so it's only a minor annoyance, but I'd like to understand the behavior.

The numbers are debug output of the string index found and are not present in non-test execution.

Comment: is `run converter` your input?  Are you expecting to get that entire string "run converter" via a single call to `cin >> run`?  The stream extraction operator (`<<`) stops on whitespace.  If you want that entire string, use `std::getline(cin, run);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is

```
> run converter
```

Then the way you are getting your input

```
cin >> run;
```

will not work for you (`operator>>` breaks on whitespace).  The first time it goes through the loop, it is going to try to find a "run" string, then it will go again and try to find a "converter" string.  If you want to deal with the whole line, you should do

```
std::getline(std::cin, run);
```

Comment: Awesome, changed cin >> run to getline(cin,run) and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should include a `continue;` at the end of each of your `if(found != string::npos)` blocks.

That way, if it executes the block, it skips the other if blocks and restarts the `while` loop.

Comment: If he wants to run multiple commands, adding `continue` to the end of each conditional block will not allow for that.

Comment: I used to have a continue in there, but then you can't run multiple commands